# How do I type the Telugu character ఎ?

Tags: keyboard, mac, language

I am trying to type the Telugu character ఎ on mac using the Telugu - QWERTY keyboard layout that ships with Mac.

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> gives me ఏ while <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> gives ఐ. I tried several other combinations that involves the <kbd>E</kbd> key, without success. Is there an easy way to type this character ఎ on Telugu QWERTY keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the ANSI keyboard (which is standard in Asia and N. and S. America), ఎ is on the Shift of the key just under ESC.  On the ISO keyboard (standard in Europe, the Middle East,  and Africa), it is on the Shift of the key just to the right of left Shift.

To verify you can use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0).

Answer (score 1):

That letter is the Telugu letter for "E".

It can be obtained by pressing the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and the key at its right with the Telugu QWERTY keyboard layout. The [keyboard viewer](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0) can help:

[image: Screenshot of the keyboard viewer when pressing ⇧]

---

You can also type it using the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout, which you can add in *System Settings > Keyboard*, next to *Input Sources*, click "Edit".

Once you have this keyboard layout in use, type **0C0E** while pressing the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key pressed to get `ఎ`.

Comment: It might help to note that, as Tom Gewecke's answer indicates, your text is talking about the ANSI keyboard, but your keyboard viewer is showing the ISO keyboard.

Comment: @shoover Oh, thanks for pointing this out. I've edited the answer accordingly ;)

Comment: @TomGewecke Oh, thanks for that. ;)